# Interpretation of diagonal detail for a 2D (Haar) Wavelet Transform

Tags: multiple-regression, signal-processing, signal-detection, wavelet

I am a statistics grad student, and I have just began exploring the topic of wavelet regression (specifically, Haar wavelets for discrete functions).  I understand the generalization from a one dimensional wavelet transform (WT) to a two-dimensional WT with respect to horizontal and vertical detail, but I have a little trouble wrapping my mind around what is meant by a ***diagonal*** detail wavelet.

- What information does a diagonal detail wavelet capture?
- How do I interpret the diagonal wavelet coefficients?
- How is direction (*lower-left to upper-right* vs *lower-right to upper-left*) captured and/or distinguished in this concept?

I greatly appreciate any feedback you can provide that might illuminate the concept.  Cheers!